# How to Debug Jsx code

Tags: javascript, webstorm, reactjs

Is there a way to debug original jsx code (and not the trasformed one)?
Maybe a Webstorm plugin or similar.

Otherwise what is the best and/or most common practice to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

No way to do this currently, please vote for [WEB-13986](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13986)